# Why does contrastive loss distinguish positive from negative samples?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, metric

Trying to learn Siamese networks for ranking tasks from [here](https://youtu.be/6e65XfwmIWE?t=1020), I find it hard to understand why the contrastive loss is not symmetric for positive and for negative examples.

The contrastive loss

$L(A, B) = y|f(A) - f(B)| + (1-y)max(0, m-|f(A) - F(B)|)$

uses a L2 norm for positive examples, but uses a hinge loss for negative examples.

The lecture doesn't explain why that is, and Googling also didn't get anything clear.

Would love a clarification on the deliberate distinction.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555954/understand-the-idea-of-margin-in-contrastive-loss-for-siamese-networks/559674#559674

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contrastive loss has 2 components:

- The positives should be close together, so minimize $\| f(A) - f(B) \|$.
- The negative portion is less obvious, but the idea is that we want negatives to be farther apart.

We can't minimize $\| f(A) - f(B) \|$ for all $A,B$, because this would just map all inputs to the same point. Instead, we want to differentiate between the classes, so we want the dissimilar classes to be far apart.

One way to move negative pairs farther apart would be to just directly maximize the distance, equivalent to minimizing $- \| f(A) - f(B) \|$. But if we do this, then the loss can decrease arbitrarily by moving all points farther apart.

Instead, we just want to move $A, B$ far *enough* apart, which is controlled by the margin. The loss is positive, until $ \| f(A) - f(B) \| > m$, and then the loss is 0. That's why the loss term for comparing negatives is $ \max\left(0, m - \| f(A) - f(B) \|\right). $ This solves the problem that the loss can decrease indefinitely, because it places a lower-bound at 0.

Comment: `but of we do this, then the loss can decrease arbitrarily by moving all points farther apart`- is that a theoretical problem, or a just practical one that would cause the net not to converge? *In theory*, what's wrong with sending far points infinitely far from each other?

Comment: If the loss can always be decreased, then the network will never converge! Minima occur where the gradient is 0 and the Hessian is positive definite. If both these conditions aren't met at any location, then there are no minima. In simpler terms, if you're minimizing the function $f(x) = ax+b$ or even $f(x) = -x^2$, there is no finite $x$ that is a minimum. For any finite $x$, you can choose another $x$ with a smaller value $f(x)$.

Comment: Is there any effect on selecting `m!=1`? Would having any different `m` would this have any effect?

Comment: Choice of $m$ just changes how widely spaced the classes' representations must be.

Comment: of course, but since the space is an embedding space, does it scale have any physical meaning? will the end result be any different with different `m`?

Comment: My previous comment answers this. I don't know how to answer your question in a way that isn't just repeating what I've already written.

Comment: The spreading of classes in the embedding space doesn't affect the end result at all, as far as my understanding goes. Is that correct?

Comment: Being more/less spread out is an effect on the result. This question doesn’t make sense.

Comment: What I mean is, if the embedding (unobserved) space is scaled by some factor, or has some arbitrary distance inherent to it, why would it have any effect on the (observed) success of clustering, or classification? After all, that space is learned. How will changing `m` effect the metrics? I see how it will change the embedding space, but isn't that arbitrary? ==> How is `m==2` different than `m==1` for the accuracy/clustering result?

Comment: Example: If `m==1` and the embedding space in one-dimensional and has 2 samples, it could put one at `(0)` and the other at `(1)`, If `m==2`, it could put one at `(0)` and the other at `(2)`. For classification, or for clustering, that is the same. I fail to see where the numerics of the embedding space matter

Comment: This comment asks a substantially different than the one in your post. It's the first time in this thread that accuracy and clustering are introduced as topics. You should clock [ASK QUESTION](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) 
link at the top of the page & ask there.

Comment: I think this is on-topic here, because it essentially asks "what does `m` do, from a user's perspective?"

Comment: That's not what your question asks, either. It's best to just ask a new question.

Comment: Please see [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/573581/why-does-cotrastive-loss-and-triplet-loss-have-the-margin-element-in-them). I think this is the correct one, if it is, please reopen :)